# calculate lm for several combinations of grouping variables

Tags: r, lm

I have a data frame with a dependent variable "my_depend" and a predictor "my_predict", a time variable "time" with two levels "20221" and "20222" and several moderators "mod1-mod5". each of the moderators has a different number of levels. For each combination of the levels of time and mod1 - mod5 I want to calculate and save the slope of the linear model predicting "dependend" from "predict". Any ideas how to approach this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please provide a [minimal reproducible example of your code and data along with relevant errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). [Edit] your question to include a [mre] so that readers can run your code to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a vector of all the right hand side (rhs) combinations, then use `lapply` to run all the models.

Reassigning the inherent `mtcars` dataset to `df` and renaming the columns per your question:

```
df <- mtcars[,1:8]
names(df) <- c("my_depend", "my_predict", "time", paste0("mod", 1:5))
```

Create a vector of combinations to put on the rhs of the `glm` formula and use it in `lapply`

```
vars <- names(df[-1])
# [1] "my_predict" "time"       "mod1"       "mod2"       "mod3"       "mod4"       "mod5"

#### all combinations of `vars`

rhs_prep <- unlist(lapply(seq(vars), combn, x = vars, paste, collapse = ' + '))
#[1] "my_predict"                                           "time"                                                 "mod1"                                                
#[4] "mod2"                                                 "mod3"                                                 "mod4"                                                
#[7] "mod5"                                                 "my_predict + time"                                    "my_predict + mod1"                                   
#[10] "my_predict + mod2"                                    "my_predict + mod3"                                    "my_predict + mod4"   
#...
#[124] "my_predict + time + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"        "my_predict + mod1 + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"        "time + mod1 + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"             
#[127] "my_predict + time + mod1 + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"

#### restrict to only those with `my_predict` and `time`

rhs_final <- rhs[grep("my_predict \\+ time", rhs)]
#[1] "my_predict + time"                                    "my_predict + time + mod1"                             "my_predict + time + mod2"                            
#[4] "my_predict + time + mod3"                             "my_predict + time + mod4"                             "my_predict + time + mod5"                            
#....
#[31] "my_predict + time + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"        "my_predict + time + mod1 + mod2 + mod3 + mod4 + mod5"

final_models <- lapply(rhs_final, function(x) 
  glm(as.formula(paste0("my_depend ~ ", x)), data = df))
```

The object `final_models` contains all the information for the various model combinations as a list.